# Google Donut Chart (Visualization) - Percentage greater than 100

Tags: charts, google-visualization, donut-chart

I am creating a donut chart using Google Visualization. Its an Monthly Revenue Goal chart. e.g. let say goal is set 1000 and 800 is the revenue then 80% will be shown as completed and 20% as remaining.
What I want to do is that if revenue is 2000 then 200% should be shown. (Visually it can not be greater than 100 (whole donut) , I just want to see the 200%.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can use the formatted value to display anything we need.

first, we need to set the following config option, to display the value of the data table column.

```
pieSliceText: 'value'
```

then when loading the data table, we use object notation to provide the formatted value, where `v:` is the value, and `f:` is the formatted value.

```
{v: 2000, f: '2,000 - 200%'}
```

with the config option above, we can display anything...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['category', 'amount'],
    ['goal', 1000],
    ['revenue', {v: 2000, f: '2,000 - 200%'}],
  ]);

  var options = {
    pieHole: 0.4,
    pieSliceText: 'value'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```css
#chart_div {
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

NOTE: but you may need to disable or provide a [custom tooltip](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#tooltiprole) to match...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['corechart']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['category', 'amount', {role: 'tooltip', type: 'string'}],
    ['goal', 1000, '1,000'],
    ['revenue', {v: 2000, f: '2,000 - 200%'}, '2,000 - 200%'],
  ]);

  var options = {
    pieHole: 0.4,
    pieSliceText: 'value'
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```css
#chart_div {
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```